# How to neatly print dictionaries with dictionaries inside

Tags: python, dictionary, printing, nested

I use the following code:

```
sick = {"Carson": {"Reason": "Broken leg on P coy", "Expiry": "2017-1-4"}, "Jackson": {"Reason": "Fell over tree root on exercise", "Expiry": "2017-2-3"}, "Ben": {"Reason": "Tripped", "Expiry": "2018-7-6"}}

def showsick():
    print "=" * 10
    print "Personnel on sick:"
    for name, reason, expiry in sick.iteritems():
        print name, ": ", reason, "\nSick chit expires: ", expiry, "\n"
    print "=" * 10
    main()
```

To try and produce an output like this:

```
Carson: Broken leg on P coy
Sick chit expires: 2017-1-4

Jackson: Fell over tree root on exercise
Sick chit expires: 2017-2-3

Ben: Tripped
Sick chit expires: 2018-7-6
```

But I get "ValueError: need more than 2 values to unpack". I've tried a number of different things including playing with json (very briefly) and pprint (again briefly), as well as a few other little things. I can't make it work though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`iteritems` only produces two pairs - key and value - at a time, so you can't unpack into three items in that `for` loop.

Instead, you want to do:

```
for name in sick:
     print name, ": ", sick[name]['Reason']
     print "Sick chit expires: ", sick[name]['Expiry']
```

Answer (score 2):

Your sick function should be like:

```
def showsick():
    print "=" * 10
    print "Personnel on sick:"
    for person, nested_dict in sick.iteritems():
        print person, ': ', nested_dict['Reason']
        print 'Sick chit expires: ', nested_dict['Expiry']
    print "=" * 10
```

Issue with your code is: `dict.iteritems()` returns tuple of `(key, value)` pair. Hence, you can wrap it in `for` with only two variables as:

```
 for x, y in dict.iteritems():
 #   ^  ^    <-- only two variables, since .iteritems() returns tuple pair of 2
```

In your code, `y` (in my example) is also a `dict`. In order to access value from it, you need to do `y[key]`.

Sample Output:

```
>>> showsick()
==========
Personnel on sick:
Carson :  Broken leg on P coy
Sick chit expires:  2017-1-4
Ben :  Tripped
Sick chit expires:  2018-7-6
Jackson :  Fell over tree root on exercise
Sick chit expires:  2017-2-3
==========
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, your answer was educational